# How do I create a non-EJB super simple web-service .war for Java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, netbeans, jboss6.x

I have been attempting to create a super simple web-service (non-SOAP wsdl Server) within Eclipse Java EE (Juno) using Java 1.6. I want the web-service war to be as simple as possible, as in [this simple](https://community.jboss.org/message/250061#250061) (first reply in the thread).

IOW, I want the war file to just have the class I have defined (which includes the @WebService and @WebMethod annotations) and possibly a web.xml file which can then be deployed in Eclipse Java EE to the JBoss 6.0 server I have set up.

I must be missing some simple step somewhere. Each time I have tried, I either cannot get the web-service to deploy, or Eclipse wants to auto-generate and add a huge number of useless classes to the deployment.

I have Eclipse Java EE set up and I created a File -> New-> Dynamic Web Project and call it ProjectHelloService. I then create a single class in the project under Java Resources/src in its own package, ws.simple. The class looks like this:

```
package ws.simple;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class HelloService
{
  @WebMethod
  public String sayHello(String name)
  {
    return "Hello, " + name;
  }
}
```

I then start up the JBoss server and "Add" the project to JBoss. I see the "...deploy, ctxPath=/ProjectHelloService" message indicating that my project has deployed. However, when I go to the default JBoss page -> JBoss Web Services Console -> View a list of deployed services, I see "There are currently no endpoints deployed ". When I dig around and try to see what was deployed in JBoss's server/default folder, I cannot find anything in the deploy folder.

Again, I must be missing some step somewhere. For example, I don't see a .war (or even .jar) file being generated, in Eclipse nor in the JBoss deploy folder. However, I am not deeply versed in the nuances of how Eclipse works with JBoss 6.0, so I might be missing some configuration subtlety here.

Is there something simple I can do to get a super stupid simple .war file to deploy to the Eclipse contained JBoss 6.0 so that I can see my web-service? And since JBoss is able to do all the auto-file generation automatically from the annotations in the .war file, I don't want Eclipse to do all the extra file stub generation crap. That's CORBA old school style, and makes for a much less manageable project (at least for the area I am working in right now).

And I don't suppose there is some way that I can have the above in Eclipse while having the convenience of the [Netbeans approach to creating and managing Java web-services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html#Exercise_1). If there is, I sure would like to know what it is.

Thank you for any guidance and/or assistance you can over here.

Comment: You do realize your title makes no sense right? A WAR is an archive for ***JEE*** apps.

Comment: Oops...yes...I meant, non-EJB...good catch, fixing...

Comment: Just sharing some experience. I faced the same problem as you do, i.e. using Eclipse with JBoss to create a simple Web service and a test client. In the end, I gave up on Eclipse and JBoss and now use NetBeans with Glassfish.

Comment: @J.Gonzalez - Tyvm! That's what I have ended up doing. I am now studying what is happening in Netbeans. Once I understand enough of the details, I will retry with Eclipse just to see if it is even possible.